# gulp wont run on gulp watch says [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

Please can someone help me, for some reason my gulp watch has stopped working. Here is the versions i am using

```
Liams-MacBook-Pro-149:pss liamhart$ gulp -v
[10:17:15] CLI version 2.0.1
[10:17:15] Local version 4.0.0-alpha.3
Liams-MacBook-Pro-149:pss liamhart$ npm -v
6.4.1
Liams-MacBook-Pro-149:pss liamhart$ node -v
v8.12.0
Liams-MacBook-Pro-149:pss liamhart$ gulp
assert.js:42
throw new errors.AssertionError({
^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (/Users/liamhart/Desktop/pss/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (/Users/liamhart/Desktop/pss/node_modules/undertaker/lib/task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/liamhart/Desktop/pss/gulpfile.js:55:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
Liams-MacBook-Pro-149:pss liamhart$
```

Answer (score 0):

Facing same issue as yours with gulp. solved it by shifting gulp version to lower one.
you can specify it in package.json also.

```
 "gulp": "3.9.1",
```

just make sure to run `npm install`.

your local version is 4.0.0-alpha.3. degrade will help you out. 
you can check gulp version list in below link.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-upload